# Is there any way somebody could hack into my brain?

Tags: physical

Before you close this, I'm actually serious. Could somebody, in theory, have conked me out behind a Chiles, circular-sawed my brain out, and plugged me up to a machine capable of brain simulation?

The simulator would be responsible for vorating the tables of signal from the "outside world" and feeding into the simulation. The numbers are crunched, computer-style, and output back to the body, itself its own system unnecessary of simulation.

Comment: I suppose this is technically on-topic. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: This is a really cool question!

Comment: The surviving documentation regarding MKULTRA may be of interest to you.  The whole thing was essentially an attempt at developing a means of hacking people's minds, albeit a somewhat low-tech one by today's standards.  I would also refer you to The Matrix and Sword Art Online, both of those show what kind of technology would be required to do the type of thing you're talking about, and cover some of the philosophical aspects of your question.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Except MKULTRA was a failure and ended up only traumatizing people.

Comment: @forest I never said it was a successful attempt, just that it was an attempt.  It's also one of the only known attempts that has any publicly available documentation, so while It may have been a failure, it's about all we've got with respect to well funded research in the area.

Comment: This is not an infosec question in any way, shape, or form. This is a neuroscience question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No one has the technology to do so, nor do we have even close to a sufficient understanding of computational neuroscience to do such a thing. We barely understand the basic way information is encoded in neural transmissions. There is absolutely no way anyone could "hack" your brain in the manner you describe with contemporary technology. While it would be possible in theory (after all, the brain is equivalent to a Turing-machine), there is no way it could actually be *done* today.

Note that [social engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_(security)) is still possible, which might be considered brain hacking, but it is nothing more than being really convincing and tricking people into doing things they otherwise wouldn't. It won't alter your state of consciousness nor tamper with or directly read out your memories.

As for the philosophical implications of such a thought experiment, they are off-topic for this site, so I won't be going into them. Neurophenomenology is not part of information security.

Comment: I'd like to add a link to this, I know patents can be found for a lot of weird stuff; but this one jumped to mind when reading the question :-)

"Neurological data can be gathered through a variety of techniques. One non-invasive technique is electroencephalography (EEG), which involves the placement of electrodes along the scalp of a user or subject to measure voltage." 

http://patft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=9864431.PN.&OS=PN/9864431&RS=PN/9864431

Comment: @Nomad An EEG probe gives you the sum of the activity of millions of cortical neurons in that general area. Trying to understand the mind with EEG is like trying to understand the habits of individual people by sampling the average light of an entire country from the upper atmosphere.

Comment: Yeah, we're certainly not there yet, not even close, and it's just a patent. But technically EEG can be used to see what centers of our brain are being stimulated. (e.g. high activity in nucleus accumbens indicates release of dopamine, which means you're happy with what you're seeing and this is possible with current technology). It's not hooking up and breaking in literally, but it's eavesdropping... in a way.

Comment: @Nomad True, and fMRI machines can tell with an even higher precision what you are thinking (to a limited extent, like roughly what you are hearing, or even what number you are thinking of).

Comment: Nice question and I want to add this : Scientists remotely hacked a brain, controlling body movements (of a mouse) the paper "Magnetothermal genetic deep brain stimulation of motor behaviors in awake, freely moving mice" is quite freaking https://elifesciences.org/articles/27069

Comment: I assume it should be "it won't alter your state of consciousness" ?